# Adding upload fields and upload content to database

Tags: php, forms, for-loop, upload

I have made a form in which I can add multiple upload fields with a button. The problem is that content of the fields created by the button are not uploaded to the database. I can't figure out if the query is the problem or my for loop? The fields created by the button do get the same name (`uploaded[]`) as the main upload field. The main upload field does get sent to the database

This is the first upload field

```
<td><label for="code">file:</td><td><input name="uploaded[]" type="file" > </label>
```

The other fields can be added like this

```
function fncCreateElement(){

    var mySpan = document.getElementById('mySpan');

    var myElement1 = document.createElement('input');
    myElement1.setAttribute('type',"file");
    myElement1.setAttribute('name',"uploaded[]");
    mySpan.appendChild(myElement1); 

    var myElement2 = document.createElement('<br>');
    mySpan.appendChild(myElement2);
}

<input name="btnButton" type="button" value="+" onClick="JavaScript:fncCreateElement();">
<span id="mySpan"> </span>
```

This is my loop to select the fields

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES["uploaded"]['name']); $i++) {



    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES["uploaded"]['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 


if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
                    //Setup our new file path
    $newFilePath = "upload/" . date("Ymd_his") . $_FILES["uploaded"]['name'][$i];
    $naam2 = $_FILES["uploaded"]['name'][$i];

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {



        $melding = "File uploaded";

    } 


    else{
        $tmpFilePath = "";
        $melding = "No file.";

    } 
}
    //Here comes the query to insert to database
}
```

The query to upload the files is placed within the loop

Does anyone see the problem in this form?

I did a var_dump on $_files as requested. The first upload field contained a text file called "File1.txt". The second field created by the button also contained a text file called "File2.txt". This is the result of the var_dump after submitting the form:

```
array(1) { ["uploaded"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "File1.txt" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "text/plain" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(27) "C:\Windows\Temp\php39E3.tmp" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } } }
```

Comment: I suggest you do a var_dump or print_r. i.e. var_dump($_FILES);. That way you can see if all the file names are arriving. Feel free to update your question with the output so we can see what is turning up.